# Why I failed to enter mysql console on remote ubuntu?

Tags: mysql

I need to replace mysql credentials on my remote ubuntu 20 server, but I failed to enter mysql console with command

```
root@remote-server:/var/www/html/project# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

root@remote-server:/var/www/html/project# dpkg -s  mysql
dpkg-query: package 'mysql' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.

root@remote-server:/var/www/html/project# dpkg -s mysql-server
Package: mysql-server
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: database
Installed-Size: 35
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: mysql-8.0
Version: 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
Depends: mysql-server-8.0
Description: MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
 This is an empty package that depends on the current "best" version of
 mysql-server (currently mysql-server-8.0), as determined by the MySQL
 maintainers. Install this package if in doubt about which MySQL
 version you need. That will install the version recommended by the
 package maintainers.
 .
 MySQL is a fast, stable and true multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database
 server. SQL (Structured Query Language) is the most popular database query
 language in the world. The main goals of MySQL are speed, robustness and
 ease of use.
Homepage: http://dev.mysql.com/
Original-Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
root@remote-server:/var/www/html/project# uname -a
Linux remote-server 5.4.0-155-generic #172-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 7 16:10:02 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@remote-server:/var/www/html/project# who -H
NAME     LINE         TIME             COMMENT
root     pts/0        2023-10-30 09:13 (213.109.234.130)
```

As I see I am under root when I opened my remote server with ssh ?
Why this error and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explanatory: the `root` user has not been given access to the mySQL database. Or, at least, the user requires a password which you are not giving. Which is good! You certainly don't want to have root playing around in a DB! Remember that DB users and systems users are different.

You need to look at your DB setup, create a user, and give that user access. If you don't know how to do this, talk to whoever is responsible for maintaining the DB.

If you are maintaining this, then I would urge you to read more about DB setup. If you still need help, then you can post a new question, explaining the setup you have and what you still need help with.

Comment: 1) which command have I to use to give user root  to the MySQL database. As mysql have several databases - it it main system database ?  2) Actually I need to runcommand : CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';

Comment: @mstdmstd 1) you don't give root access. And I don't know what DB it is, that is something you need to check. 2) yes, but again, this all depends on your specific setup and needs, there is no general solution. We would need to know MUCH more about what you are doing to be able to help. Consider asking a new question where you explain your requirements in detail.